# Error: 'app-header' is not a known element despite adding 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'

Tags: angular, components

Even though the 'app-header' component is being rendered in the browser, the content in the corresponding "header.component.ts" or "header.component.html" is not being displayed.

[image: Screenshot]

```bash
error: 'app-header' is not a known element:
If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I have verified that 'app-header' is indeed part of the module.
- I have added 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of the module to suppress the error.

My goal is to resolve this issue and ensure that the content in 'app-header' is displayed as expected ("header works").

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was declare it in *app.module.ts* and in "exports".

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]
```

Comment: If you have a question please post it separately as a standalone post ([ask]). Avoid doing that in the answer box as it is for **answers only** ([answer]).

Answer (score 0):

to use `app-header` inside of `app-component` template angular should know what is the compile scope of these components. By default any component can use basic elements in their template like `<input>` or simple `div`.

by adding `HeaderComponent` into a module's `declarations` you are bascally setting the compile scope for AppComponent and for HeaderComponent and they know about each other and can use tags to render.

`exports` in your case is irrelevant and could be removed. exports can be used to make modules which expose several components to the outer world. for example custom select with custom options could have such module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomSelectComponent,
    CustomOptionComponent,
    CustomOptionsListComponent, // we don't want this one to be used by user code. it is just for internal use

  ],
  exports: [
    CustomSelectComponent,
    CustomOptionComponent,
    // no CustomOtionsListComponent exported
  ]
})
```